# How to read last 3 variable values from .txt file using C

Tags: c

I have limited experience programming in C, but have to use this language due to software constraints. I'm trying to write a user customisation for a CFD software.

The software writes an output file during the calculation, I want to monitor the variable "PERCENT FILLED" and terminate the simulation when the value stabilizes. I can do the termination of the code, the issue I am having is reading in the value for PERCENT FILLED using C, I can easily do this in python or shell script, but am really struggling with C.

There may be a much more elegant way of doing this, I'm happy to learn, but I'm not an experienced programmer, so I may get lost with complex solutions.

I have tried to do this by breaking the task into smaller sub tasks. The efficiency of the code is not important as this function does not have to be run frequently and the file to be read is not very large. I am sure there are faster and more elegant ways of doing this!
Using others code from the web and modifying them I have come up with the below.

I tried to do the following sub tasks:
A) Strip all lines containing "PERCENT FILLED" and write them to a file (PERCENT FILLED.txt)
B) Read the number of lines in this file, then read the last 3 lines into separate variables. 
C) I then need to reformat these variables. For example, change the 3 variables from strings of the form "PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00" into a floats of values such as 6.72902.

I have completed A), have an error in B), and can't work out where to start with C).

ERROR in B) - When I run the code it correctly assigns values for line1, line2, and line3 whilst in the while loop, however once outside the while loop all values change to that of line1. This I do not understand. Can anyone help me understand and resolve this?

Example code output:

```
line3: PERCENT FILLED =   6.31275E+00
line2: PERCENT FILLED =   6.50146E+00
line1: PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00
****************** 
out line1: PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00
out line2: PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00
out line3: PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00
```

Part C) - I have no idea where to start with this. It looks like there is enough information inline to use atof() for the conversion of the string to a float. However, I first need to remove  PERCENT FILLED = from the start of the string and then convert the engineering number format (some values are 1.00E+02 so simply stripping the last 4 characters - E+00 - will not work). This I can't work out how to do. any help would be appreciated.

Example input file (simplified by removing may lines between the PERCENT FILLED values):

```
  Step = 171 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.014849 Time = 4.834002
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC     4   1.0000000E+00       0.007999       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   5.46882E+00
  Step = 172 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.029698 Time = 4.863700
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC    11   1.0000000E+00       0.018997       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   5.70902E+00
  Step = 173 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.029698 Time = 4.893398
  Time step reduced by COURANT limit in free_surface, c_lim = 2.032750e-02
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC     6   1.0000000E+00       0.010998       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   5.89665E+00
  Step = 174 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.020328 Time = 4.904356
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC     7   1.0000000E+00       0.011997       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   6.08026E+00
  Step = 175 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.040655 Time = 4.945011
  Time step reduced by COURANT limit in free_surface, c_lim = 2.547617e-02
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC     9   1.0000000E+00       0.016998       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   6.31275E+00
  Step = 176 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.025476 Time = 4.955307
  Time step reduced by COURANT limit in free_surface, c_lim = 1.997734e-02
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC     9   1.0000000E+00       0.016994       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   6.50146E+00
  Step = 177 Iteration = 0 Time step = 0.039955 Time = 4.989764
  Time step reduced by COURANT limit in free_surface, c_lim = 2.547537e-02
  Iter Variable Solver Loops          Delta      Solve CPU       Form CPU
     0        F  EXPLC    13   1.0000000E+00       0.024994       0.000000
 FRACTION SOLID = 0.000000e+00 %
 PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00
```

My current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    char *pch;
    char c[] = "PERCENT FILLED =";
    char buff[1000];


/* Create a list of PERCENT FILLED values and write to file - copy every line containing PERCENT FILLED from p.out file*/
    FILE *fp = fopen("inputFILE.txt", "r");
    FILE *op = fopen("PERCENT_FILLED.txt", "w");

    if(fp == NULL || op == NULL)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
          exit(1);
       }
    else 
       {
         while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
           {
              if((pch = strstr (line, c))!= 0)
              fprintf(op, "%s", line);
           }
       }

   fclose(fp);
   fclose(op);


/* Get the total number of lines in the file PERCENT_FILLED.txt   */

   FILE* myfile = fopen("PERCENT_FILLED.txt", "r");
   int ch, number_of_lines = 0;
   int line_num = 0;
   int count = 0;
   char readline[256];                                /* or other suitable maximum line size */
   char* line1;
   char* line2;
   char* line3;

    do 
    {
        ch = fgetc(myfile);
        if(ch == '\n')
            number_of_lines++;
    } while (ch != EOF);

    // last line doesn't end with a new line!
    // but there has to be a line at least before the last line
    if(ch != '\n' && number_of_lines != 0) 
        number_of_lines++;

    fclose(myfile);




/* Get the last 3 PERCENT_FILLED values from the PERCENT_FILLED.txt   */


    FILE* infile = fopen("PERCENT_FILLED.txt", "r");

    if ( infile != NULL )
    {   
        while (fgets(readline, sizeof line, infile) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {   
            if (count == (number_of_lines-4))
            {   
               line3 = readline;
               count++;
               printf("\nline3:%s", line3);
            }   
            else if (count == (number_of_lines-3))
            {  
               line2 = readline;
               count++;
               printf("line2:%s", line2);
            }
            else if (count == (number_of_lines-2))
            {
               line1 = readline;
               count++;
               printf("line1:%s", line1);
            }
            else
            {   
                count++;
                printf("readline:%s count:%d\n", readline, count);
            }   
        }   
        fclose(infile);
    }   
    printf("******************\n");
    printf("out line1:%s", line1);
    printf("out line2:%s", line2);
    printf("out line3:%s\n\n", line3);


/* strip "PERCENT FILLED = " from the string and turn the string into a float  */
/* Do this for line1, line2, line3 */
/* Example string is "  PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00" need to turn this in to a float variable of value 6.72902 */

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: See `man sscanf`, read from the string, get the data you would like via a format specifier and variable, then format your output from the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, I have the code working now as shown below. I'm sure there is a much more elegant way of doing this, but for completeness i'll put up my final code in case it can help someone.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    char *pch;
    char c[] = "PERCENT FILLED =";
    char buff[1000];


/* Create a list of PERCENT FILLED values and write to file - copy every line containing PERCENT FILLED from p.out file*/
    FILE *fp = fopen("inputFILE.txt", "r");
    FILE *op = fopen("PERCENT_FILLED.txt", "w");

    if(fp == NULL || op == NULL)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
          exit(1);
       }
    else 
       {
         while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
           {
              if((pch = strstr (line, c))!= 0)
              fprintf(op, "%s", line);
           }
       }

   fclose(fp);
   fclose(op);


/* Get the total number of lines in the file PERCENT_FILLED.txt   */

   FILE* myfile = fopen("PERCENT_FILLED.txt", "r");
   int ch, number_of_lines = 0;
   int line_num = 0;
   int count = 0;
   char readline[256];                                /* or other suitable maximum line size */
   char line1[256];
   char line2[256];
   char line3[256];

    do 
    {
        ch = fgetc(myfile);
        if(ch == '\n')
            number_of_lines++;
    } while (ch != EOF);

    // last line doesn't end with a new line!
    // but there has to be a line at least before the last line
    if(ch != '\n' && number_of_lines != 0) 
        number_of_lines++;

    fclose(myfile);




/* Get the last 3 PERCENT_FILLED values from the PERCENT_FILLED.txt   */


    FILE* infile = fopen("PERCENT_FILLED.txt", "r");

    if ( infile != NULL )
    {   
        while (fgets(readline, sizeof line, infile) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {   
            if (count == (number_of_lines-4))
            {   
               strcpy ( line3, readline);
               count++;
            }   
            else if (count == (number_of_lines-3))
            {  
               strcpy ( line2, readline);
               count++;
            }
            else if (count == (number_of_lines-2))
            {
               strcpy ( line1, readline);
               count++;
            }
            else
            {   
                count++;
            }   
        }   
        fclose(infile);
    }      

/* strip "PERCENT FILLED = " from the string and turn the string into a float  */
/* Do this for line1, line2, line3 */
/* Example string is "  PERCENT FILLED =   6.72902E+00" need to turn this in to a float varaible of value 6.72902 */

    char per1[7], fil1[6], eq1[1];
    char per2[7], fil2[6], eq2[1];
    char per3[7], fil3[6], eq3[1];
    float value1, value2, value3;

    sscanf (line1, "%s %s %s %E", per1, fil1, eq1, &value1 );
    sscanf (line2, "%s %s %s %E", per2, fil2, eq2, &value2 );
    sscanf (line3, "%s %s %s %E", per3, fil3, eq3, &value3 );

    printf("Value1: %f\n", value1 );
    printf("Value2: %f\n", value2 );    
    printf("Value3: %f\n", value3 );


    return 0;

    }
```